# When do I need to use worker processes in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a Node.js app with a small set of users that is currently architected with a single web process. I'm thinking about adding an after save trigger that will get called when a record is added to one of my tables. When that after save trigger is executed, I want to perform a large number of IO operations to external APIs. The number of IO operations depends on the number of elements in an array column on the record. Thus, I could be performing a large number of asynchronous operations after each record is saved in this particular table.

I thought about moving this work to a background job as suggested in [Worker Dynos, Background Jobs and Queueing](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing). The article gives as a rule of thumb that tasks that take longer than 500 ms be moved to background job. However, after working through the example using RabbitMQ ([Asynchronous Web-Worker Model Using RabbitMQ in Node](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/asynchronous-web-worker-model-using-rabbitmq-in-node)), I'm not convinced that it's worth the time to set everything up.

So, my questions are:

- For an app with a limited amount of concurrent users, is it ok to leave a long-running function in a web process?
- If I eventually decide to send this work to a background job it doesn't seem like it would be that hard to change my after save trigger. Am I missing something?
- Is there a way to do this that is easier than implementing a message queue?

Comment: How long-running? Heroku's router will kill a request that takes more than 30 seconds. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

Comment: No, it definitely wouldn't take that long. I think it would be less than 10 seconds.

Comment: Then as long as the users who'll encounter that long request don't mind, you're fine putting this off to later.

Comment: Gotcha. So the 500 ms rule of thumb is more of a best practice for creating responsive apps?

Comment: Yes. It's not a technical limitation or anything Heroku enforces (unlike the 30s limit). It's just a best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For an app with a limited amount of concurrent users, is it ok to leave a long-running function in a web process?

this is more a question of preference, than anything.

in general i say no - it's not ok... but that's based on experience in building rabbitmq services that run in heroku workers, and not seeing this as a difficult thing to do.

with a little practice, you may find that this is the simpler solution, as I have (it allows simpler code, and more robust code, as it splits the web away from the background processor - allowing each to run without knowing about each other directly)

> If I eventually decide to send this work to a background job it doesn't seem like it would be that hard to change my after save trigger. Am I missing something?

are you missing something? not really

as long as you write your current in-the-web-process code in a well structured and modular fashion, moving it to a background process is not usually a big deal

most of the panic that people get from having to move code into the background, comes from having their code tightly coupled to the HTTP request / response process (i know from personal experience how painful it can be)

> Is there a way to do this that is easier than implementing a message queue?

there are many options for distributed computing and background processing. i personally like RabbitMQ and the messaging patterns that it uses.

i would suggest giving it a try and seeing if it's something that can work well for you.

other options include redis with pub/sub libraries on top of it, using direct HTTP API calls to another web server, or just using a timer in your background process to check database tables on a given frequency and having the code run based on the data it finds.

p.s. you may find my RabbitMQ For Developers course of interest, if you are wanting to dig deeper into RMQ w/ node: http://rabbitmq4devs.com

Comment: Wow, this is super helpful. Coincidentally, your article Properly Handling Webhooks With Node and Express was one of the ones that I read through and bookmarked in my deep-dive on the topic yesterday. Thanks! One additional question: if I use a direct http call to another server, can I immediately send a "200 Ok" response then continue to execute the rest of the function? In my case the caller does not need to know that the callee completed successfully.

Comment: you could do that - immediately send 200 OK and then finish the processing. but this could lead to other problems. the client would never know that the server errored, etc.